# Powershell: Search for a match in position 68-70 then extract field position 2-9

Tags: powershell, search, match

I need to split a text file that contains 10K+ lines, some of which contain information about files.  Each line of interest contains the string `"VER"` in position (column) 68-70 and the name of the file - which is the information I'm trying to extract - is found in position 2-9.

It looks like this...
the file name is `ACCRLINK`

```
 ACCRLINK                         VER     1   176      D                                    03/09/98 02/21/84
```

Below is my attempt *with pseudo code* that hopefully illustrates what I am after.

Can anyone help me alter the script to select *by position* and capture the file name in another position?

Thank you,

-Ron

```
$InputFile = "C:\RECORDS_cpy.txt"
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
#$a = 1
$OPName = @()
While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    If ($Line -match "VER"(68,3)) {
        $OPName = $Line(2,8)
        $FileName = $OPName.Trim()
        Write-Host "Found ... $FileName" -foregroundcolor green
        $OutputFile = "$FileName.txt"
        #$a++
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
}
```

Comment: Can the file names inside the file have spaces in them, or do they always consists of consecutive letters?

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen,
No they cannot have spaces within the name.
-Ron

Comment: Hello, can you provide an example of of a line that match NEWTEXT= ?

Answer (score 0):

This code ignores the position issues and looks entirely at the pattern.  You need the lines that have "NEWTEXT" with an "=" followed by the desired text and then followed by VER and maybe some other random text.

```
function GetFileNames([string]$FileName) {
    switch -Regex -File $FileName {
        '^\s*NEWTEXT\s*=\s*(?<File>.*?)\s*VER\s*.*$' {$Matches.File}
        default {continue}
    }
}
$InputFile = "C:\RECORDS_cpy.txt"
$OutFile = "C:\RECORDS_Results.txt"
GetFileNames $InputFile | Out-File $OutFile
```

When ran, the file C:\RECORDS_Results.txt contains this:

```
ACCRLINK
```

Comment: Hi Darin..
I altered the script above to look sort of what I need.  The script no longer works for syntax reasons but hopefully it shows what I'm looking for.  I need to verify that the letters "VER" are present in positions 68-70 on a line.  If they are, I need to capture the characters in position 2-9 on the same line.

Is that possible?

-Ron

Comment: Guys - This is my fault - I am asking the question wrong and not providing enough context.
I am going to start an new thread from scratch and add as much information as I can.

Thank you all for your help - See you in the next thread!!!!

-Ron

Comment: User3166462, the "However, this substring-based approach does not work." kind of throws me for a loop.  How do we test the content for "VER" if we can't use commands like $Line.Substring(68,3).  Similary, how do we get the file name if we can do $Line.Substring(2,8)?  You are complaining that the Substring approach doesn't work, so we are giving you alternatives  - but you aren't liking the alternatives.

Comment: @Darin, I edited that phrase into the question, and I see that it is ambiguous: I should have said "substring-_matching_ approach", which referred to the original `-match "NEWTEXT="` approach (since removed from the question). Since Ron has since replaced that code, I've edited the question again. In short: yes, looking at substrings _at fixed positions_ is a requirement, which can be done with multiple `.Substring()` calls or, more succinctly, with a single regex.

Comment: Ron has since posted a new question with more details, so I've closed this one as a duplicate (though it would be better to delete it): https://stackoverflow.com/q/71242192/45375