# Powershell: Split a single file into multiple files - using string match criteria

Tags: string, powershell, match

I have a single file that contains 1GB worth of data.  This data is actually 10's of thousands of individual mini files.
I need to extract each individual file and place them in their own separate Distinct file.
So essentially, I need to go from a single file to 30K+ separate files.

Here is a sample of what My file looks like.

> FILENAM1                          VER     1    32      D
> 10/15/87 09/29/87
> PREPARED BY          ?????
> REVISED BY           ?????
> DESCRIPTION          USER DOMAIN
> RECORD               FILENAM1                                  VER     1 D  SUFFIX -4541
> 100   05 ST-CTY-CDE-FMHA-4541                                                      DISPLAY
> 200    10 ST-CDE-FMHA-4541                        9(2)                             DISPLAY
> 300    10 CTY-CDE-FMHA-4541                       9(3)                             DISPLAY
> 400   05 NME-CTY-4541                             X(20)                            DISPLAY
> 500   05 LST-UPDTE-DTE-4541                       9(06)                            DISPLAY
> 600   05 FILLER                                   X                                DISPLAY                                1REPORT NO. 08
> DATA DICTIONARY REPORTER  REL 17.0                       09/23/21
> PAGE     2   DREPORT 008
> RECORD REPORT
>
> -************************************************************************************************************************************
> RECORD               RECORD                    ---- D A T E ----
> RECORD NAME                                LENGTH  BUILDER        TYPE
> OCCURRENCES   UPDATED   CREATED
> ************************************************************************************************************************************ 0
> FILENAM2                         VER     1   176      D
> 03/09/98 02/21/84
> PREPARED BY          ??????
> REVISED BY           ??????
> DEFINITION

I Need split the files out based upon a match of VER in position 68, 69 and 70.  I also need to name each file uniquely.  That information is stored on the same line in position 2-9.  In the example above that string is "FILENAM1" and FILENAM2".

So just using the example above I would create two output files and they would be named FILENAM1.txt and FILENAM2.txt.

Since I have 30K+ files I need to split, doing this manually is impossible.

I do have a script that will split a file into multiple files but it will not search for strings by position.

Would anyone be able to assist me with this?

Here is script that DOES NOT Work.  Hopefully I can butcher it and get some valid results....

```
$InputFile = "C:\COPIES.txt"
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
$OPName = @()
While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    If ($Line -match "VER"(67,3)) {
        $OPName = $Line.(2,8)
        $FileName = $OPName[1].Trim()
        Write-Host "Found ... $FileName" -foregroundcolor green
        $OutputFile = "$FileName.txt"
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
}
```

Thank you in advance,

-Ron

Comment: Can we assume there will be no file collision ? Meaning, `FILENAMXXX` __will be unique__ ?

Comment: Also, please add an example of how both files should look as a result of the script

Comment: I now see that there is indeed more to your question than in your [previous attempt to ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71238348/45375) -  I suggest deleting the latter.

Comment: There should be no file collision.

I will add output structure to the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement, which offers both convenient and fast line-by-line reading of files via `-File` and [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-matching via `-Regex`:

```
$streamWriter = $null
switch -CaseSensitive -Regex -File "C:\COPIES.txt" {
  '^.(.{8}).{58}VER' { # Start of a new embedded file.
    if ($streamWriter) { $streamWriter.Close() } # Close previous output file.
    # Create a new output file.
    $fileName = $Matches[1].Trim() + '.txt'
    $streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter] (Join-Path $PWD.ProviderPath $fileName)
    $streamWriter.WriteLine($_)
  }
  default { # Write subsequent lines to the same file.
    if ($streamWriter) { $streamWriter.WriteLine($_) }
  }
}
$streamWriter.Close()
```

<sup>Note: A solution using the `.Substring()` method of the `[string]` type is possible too, but would be more verbose.</sup>

- The `^.(.{8}).{58}` portion of the regex matches the first 67 characters on each line, while capturing those in (1-based) columns 2 through 9 (the file name) via capture group `(.{8})`, which makes the captured text available in index `[1]` of the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches). The `VER` portion of the regex then ensures that the line only matches if `VER` is found at column position 68.
- For efficient output-file creation, [`[System.IO.StreamWriter]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter) instances are used, which is much faster than line-by-line `Add-Content` calls. Additionally, with `Add-Content` you'd have to ensure that a target file doesn't already exist, as the existing content would then be appended to.